# Obtain Access Into the Camera Roll Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am having an issue getting into the camera roll folder for Windows Phone 8. Unfortunately due to the project being a MonoGame Project, the MediaLibrary object is not implemented and thus does not work. I am left with having to directly tap into the camera roll folder directly, through I am getting an

```
Access Denied
```

Error as a result. The idea is that if I know the location of the file in the future, I can display it in certain parts of my app after the user has taken a photo using the app. The code is as follows:

```
StorageFile folder = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("Pictures\\Camera Roll\\WP_20130227_001.jpg");
```

I have also checked off:

```
ID_MEDIALIB_PHOTO
```

and am still getting the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes and no. If you are not using Monogame you can look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx . Unfortunately Monogame does not implement the media library at the moment on he windows phone

Answer (score 0):

Try using the photochoosertask..

```
        PhotoChooserTask selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
        selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectphoto_Completed);
        selectphoto.Show();
```

this might help.

Comment: Hmmm, ok let me try this out. I'll let you know how it goes!